# Is it possible to log the SQL queries between a Delphi app and a MsAccess DB?

Tags: delphi, ado

I have a Delphi 7 app using `ADO/MSDASQL.1` provider and I wonder if it is possible to "log" the SQL queries sent to the DB in a easy way? Just like the SQL profiler in SQL Server?

Answer (score 6):

Inside your application you can log the commands in TADOConnection.OnWillExecute event, you only have to save the CommandText, but you can also log a lot of other options.

```
procedure TForm23.ADOConnection1WillExecute(Connection: TADOConnection; var
  CommandText: WideString; var CursorType: TCursorType; var LockType:
  TADOLockType; var CommandType: TCommandType; var ExecuteOptions:
  TExecuteOptions; var EventStatus: TEventStatus; const Command: _Command;
  const Recordset: _Recordset);
begin
   LogToFile( CommandText );
end;
```

Comment: I can only log selects this way, how i can log other types of queries?

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar, but all my queries go through a single point. It was a simple change to add logging at this point. Another option would be to create a TLogADOQuery class which descends from TADOQuery, and override **ExecuteSQL** and **Open** to log the SQL going to the database. You then replace all references to TADOQuery, with your new class.